# Making the "ls" command sort "a" before "B" (vs a->b->A->B)

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal

I am trying to find a way to have the results of an ls command be printed in a case insensitive manner.

currently an ls command results in:

```
Apple
Boy
Chart
Dock
apples
boys
charts
docks
```

what i want is this:

```
Apple
apples
Boy
boys
Chart
charts
Dock
docks
```

is this possible?

Comment: Funny; one of my frustrations is that I get the case-insensitive sorting which annoys the living daylights out of me because I'm so used to exploiting the case-sensitive version to get files starting with capital letters at the start of the listing, but they don't appear there any more.  That's because I use an `en_US.utf8` locale, which is mostly right.  So, I agree with most of Keith's observations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macOS Terminal: \`ls\` sorts results with capitalised names first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833833/macos-terminal-ls-sorts-results-with-capitalised-names-first)

Comment: @LiranH how can this be a duplicate? this was asked 5.5 years ago.. the question you reference was asked 3 months ago.. I think you've got it backwards.. lol this post is even referenced in the accepted answer of your own post..

Comment: @Andrew I thought the same as you, but then was corrected by Zoe in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836993/2884291 (further down in this thread).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ls` (at least if you're using the GNU coreutils version; `ls --version` to check that) sorts file names according to the current locale.

The set of available locales varies from system to system (`locale -a` for a list), but on my system this:

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 ls
```

sorts names with `a` and `A` before `b` and `B` -- though it might not be *exactly* in the order you're looking for.

This works even when `ls` lists files in multiple columns, something that's difficult to do with `sort -f`.

(I have `$LC_COLLATE` set to `C` specifically so that locale-sensitive sorting is done in ASCII order.)

Comment: so @keith I did a quick google search and am not exactly sure how to change mine. I think you might be correct that this is what i need, would this be something that should be in a .bashrc file? it looks like my locale is set to:
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: @Andrew: It's like setting any other environment variable (and don't forget to `export` it). If you always want the same settings, adding the appropriate command to your `.bashrc` is probably the way to go. Note that your locale will also affect shell wildcard expansion (`echo *`) and even the `sort` command. But with `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` you *should* be getting the ordering you want. What system are you on?

Comment: right this moment im using a mac but the problem happens more at work, on a solaris machine.

Comment: @Andrew: Ok, I mostly use Linux. Check your systems' man pages and/or play around to see how `ls` and other commands respond to locale settings.

Comment: I tested on a Linux system and `LC_COLLATE=C` did not work for me, but `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` did. I put the following in my startup script:  
`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`  
`export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: @Emanuel: Right, I wouldn't expect `LC_COLLATE=C` to work for you. It does work for me because I *want* simple ASCII sorting, with `A`..`Z` preceding `a`..`z`.

Comment: Tested in powershell (Windows 10, Powershell 5.1...) works with a simple `$env:LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8'` thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just pipe the result to [`sort -f`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort).

Comment: Won't work for `ls -R`

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to [Keith Thompson]'s answer, I tested on a Linux system and LC_COLLATE=C did not work for me, but LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" did. I put the following in my startup script:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

This did not work on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

```
# alias ll='(LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 && export LC_COLLATE && shopt -s nocaseglob && /bin/ls -alF --color=auto )'
# ll
```

Answer (score 0):

ls --format=single-column | sort -f

Answer (score -2):

Add to .profile:

```
alias llg='ls -ltr | grep -i'
```

then you can use following command:

```
llg "week"
```

Comment: The `t` and `r` options tell `ls` to sort chronologically, oldest first, newest last. The OP wants to sort by name, case-insensitively.