# macOS Terminal: `ls` sorts results with capitalised names first

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

How can I fix this default sorting behaviour for `ls` in the macOS Terminal? I want the results to be case-insensitive and alphabetised.

Here is an example to illustrate the current and desired behaviours when running `ls` in a directory with the files/directories: Apple_, apple, Basket_, basket

**Current behaviour:**

Apple_

Basket_

apple

basket

**Desired behaviour:**

Apple_

apple

Basket_

basket

---

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This no longer works

So @Yoric was very close, but the content of his function was a bit wrong: it would indeed sort the results alphabetically, but when using the `-la' flag, it would mess up the order of the "dot" files/directories (those beginning with a dot).

**I found the correct solution by adapting the one in the following Stack Overflow post**: [Making the "ls" command sort "a" before "B" (vs a->b->A->B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413646/case-insensitive-unix-ls-command)

### Steps:

1. Open/create your shell profile file in your home directory (`~/`). (This file is automatically run every time you launch the shell). This would be:

- `.bash_profile` if not using a configuration framework
- `.zshrc` if using zsh

2. Add the following code

---

```
ls_sort() {
  LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 ls "$@"
}

alias ls='ls_sort'
```

---

3. Restart your Terminal

---

Thank you @Yoric for helping me to get to this solution!

Comment: Use `"$@"` (including the double-quotes) instead of `$1` -- as written, it cannot handle multiple filenames/options on the command line. To see the problem, try `ls *` and see what happens.

Comment: This does not change the sorting for me on macOS 10.14 (and most likely also previous versions since APFS). I have the correct `locale` by default and still don't get case insensitive sorting.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that it doesn't work anymore. Would be great if someone could share a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort like this:

```
$ mkdir testdir && cd testdir
$ touch apple basket Apple_ Basket_
$ ls | LC_COLLATE=C sort --ignore-case
```

The output (not exactly the expected result, actually):

```
Apple
apple_
basket
Basket_
```

---

**UPDATE**

To make it the default behavior of `ls`, you can add this piece of code into the file `~/.bash_profile` (it will be effective after opening a new terminal window):

```
ls_sort() {
  ls $1 | LC_COLLATE=C sort --ignore-case
}
alias ls='ls_sort'
```

You can actually name the alias `lss` instead of `ls` in the last line above, so you don't lose the original behavior of `ls`.

Comment: Thanks Yoric. Do you know of a way to make this the default behaviour when running `ls`?

Comment: I updated my message for making it the default behavior of `ls`

Comment: Also this answer does not work for me on APFS, the sort order is actually not identifiable (A*, D*, l*, s*, p*, w*, m*, p*, D*, M*, ... is what I get)

Comment: This indeed sorts the results alphabetically, but when using the `-la' flag, it messes up the order of the "dot" files/directories (those beginning with a dot). I still don't have a working solution for this to this day

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
ls | sort -f
```